# Twig: Set onclick-handler (jsonArray). Syntax error

Tags: symfony, twig

How can i set my onclick-var without syntax errors?

```
{% if active is defined and active == false %}
    {% set onclick = 'javascript:void(0); false;' %}
{% else %}
    {% set onclick = "myApp.dialog.show({
            'title': '{{ 'app.title'|trans({}, 'MyBundle') }}',
            'width': '{{ dialog.width }}',
            'height': '{{ dialog.height }}'
        });"
    %}
{% endif %}
<button onclick="{{ onclick }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation over here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) you can use the `set` tag for capturing the data:

```
{% if active is defined and active == false %}
    {% set onclick = 'javascript:void(0); false;' %}
{% else %}
    {% set onclick %}
        myApp.dialog.show({
            'title': '{{ 'app.title'|trans({}, 'MyBundle') }}',
            'width': '{{ dialog.width }}',
            'height': '{{ dialog.height }}'
        });
    {% endset %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to make a macro of this, to abstract away the implementation from the view to a separate file:

```
{% macro clickHandler(active) %}
    {% if active is defined and active == false %}
        javascript:void(0); false;
    {% else %}
        myApp.dialog.show({
            'title': '{{ 'app.title'|trans({}, 'MyBundle') }}',
            'width': '{{ dialog.width }}',
            'height': '{{ dialog.height }}'
        });
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Would make:

```
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}
<button onclick="{{ macros.clickHandler(activeState) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html